# Scheduling task from Django admin Panel

Tags: django, django-admin, celery, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule a task in Django which would run at a paticular time every day.I am thinking of using celery to schedule the tasks so I wanted to know is there anyway through celery-beat I could execute the task through admin panel that is make it active or inactive and give the time at which I want to execute task through my admin site.Instead of writing this in my code

```
crontab(day_of_week="0,6", hour="0,12", minute=15)
```

I want to pass it through my admin panel so that in future if I want to execute my task at some other time I could change it directly through admin panel instead of changing my code.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to implement that on your own or use a third-party project. Luckily, someone already created something like that:

https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/

> This extension enables you to store the periodic task schedule in the
>   database.
>
> The periodic tasks can be managed from the Django Admin interface,
>   where you can create, edit and delete periodic tasks and how often
>   they should run.

Comment: Hi,Have you used this extension?When I change the crontab from admin panel for a task the task is not executed on the specified time.